# Does Xn converge to Po(λ) if Yn does?

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose that Yn is known to converge in distribution to Po(λ) as n-> ∞. We also know that E[Xn] = E[Yn] for all values of n. Can we then assert that Xn converges in distribution to Po(λ)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

No. We may even have $X_n=EY_n=\lambda$ for all $n$ in which case $X_n \to \lambda$.

Comment: What if we specify that both Xn is a summation of terms A1 + A2 + … An, where each Ai has a non-zero probability of being a particular integer value. We then specify that Yn is a summation of terms B1 + B2 + … + Bn, where each Bi has a non-zero probability of being a particular integer value.

Comment: @ToddDavidson EX_n=EY_N$ is too weak a condition to say anything  more about the distribution functions.